# why, if i leave so long form page, ajax can't send my request in that page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

for a short time, jQuery is worked and success in $.ajax method.
and why the jquery ajax can not be ignored for so long?

```
function linked(terget_php,token){
    $.ajax({
        url:"php/"+terget_php,
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"HTML",
        data:"token="+token,
        beforeSend:function(){
            $("#loading").fadeIn('fast');
        },
        success:function(html){
            $("#all_load_menu").html(html);
            $("#loading").fadeOut('fast');
        }
    });
}
```

Information :

```
i use in last mozilla firefox
i tested from private and non private browser
i fixed / remove some sytax from comment
```

Comment: browser cache? we need more details.

Comment: `why the jquery ajax can not be ignored for so long?` I've been ignoring the code in your question for a minute now ... nothing bad has happene.... OH MY GOD, my dog caught fire!!!

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: don't use `async:false`

Comment: Note, `typeData` should be `dataType`

Comment: @Jaromanda X,
i try your answare, but is not worked

Comment: @guest271314 i thanks, but it's not worked too

Comment: I'm curious to see how you tried my answer

Comment: sorry, i not focus. but please help me

Comment: Does `html` include `#loading` element? Did you remove `async:false`? Can you reproduce issue at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: in that syntax i using a ajax form jquery, and that just part of my project, sorry i can't give you example form jsfiddle.net, but my question is, why in ajax of jquery can't load my request to target (url) if i leave so long

Comment: @AbdulAzizAlBasyir - I didn't post an answer, so don't accuse my answer of not working. If you don't use async:false, that will make the request asynchronous ... then you'll have to learn how to use asynchronous code correctly

Comment: @Jaromanda X, i try your answare, but is not worked - sorry i not focus in this comment, i - **sorry, i not focus. but please help me – Abdul Aziz Al Basyir 12 mins ago**  - this comment is for you,

Comment: Without more context I can't help you

Comment: so, describe what the problem is when you "ignored for so long" ... async:true (or no async parameter at all) should fix any issues regarding the script "blocking" the browser, but as the actual problem you are having is unclear, I can't say what the solution is

Comment: @Jaromanda X, maybe i give you structure in my mind. if you click a button `< button onclick="linked('test/request.php','{token_code}')">`browser can load page and replace it in $("#all_load_menu"), same in .load() function, but load function CAN'T give a SPACE.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox delete your browser history and retry. Some of the changes that you made to your code might not have been reinstated due to browser cache.

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/browser-cache-makeuseof-explains/

Comment: thanks for responded, but that not my answare, i change my question, why? because many people can't know what i needed...